# stopping threads and where to use locks

Tags: java, multithreading

My problem is where to use the locks on these threads. When I have my circles race eachother, when one reaches the end the program should stop and declare a winner. Instead, it finishes all of the circles to the finish line, I believe this is due to them all sharing the same lock and maybe even resources.

Here are three of my classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class HorsePanel extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel;
private JButton reset;
private JButton quit;
private JButton run;
private ActionListener listener;
public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

private TrackPane trackPane;

public HorsePanel(TrackPane t) {
    trackPane = t;
    createPanel();
    createRunRace();
    createQuit();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

public void createRunRace() {

    class RunRace implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rightEvent) {
            run.setEnabled(false);
            trackPane.start();

        }
    }

    ActionListener a = new RunRace();
    this.run.addActionListener(a);
}

public void createQuit() {
    class QuitRace implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rightEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    ActionListener b = new QuitRace();
    this.quit.addActionListener(b);
}


public void createReset() {
    class ResetRace implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent rightEvent) {
            //trackPane.resetCoordinates;
            run.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    ActionListener c = new ResetRace();
    this.reset.addActionListener(c);
}

public void createPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    trackPane = new TrackPane();
    this.run = new JButton("Run Race");
    this.quit = new JButton("Quit");
    this.reset = new JButton("Reset");
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    topPanel.add(run);
    topPanel.add(reset);
    topPanel.add(quit);
    panel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(trackPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panel);
}
}




import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class HorseTester {
public static TrackPane t = new TrackPane();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HorseTester();
}

public HorseTester() {
    JFrame frame = new HorsePanel(t);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HorseThread implements Runnable {

public static final int X_START = 10;
public static final int Y_START = 20;
private boolean RUNNING = true;
public int FINISH_LINE = 450;
private Horse horse;
private int xpos, ypos;
private TrackPane track;
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public int id;

public HorseThread(TrackPane track, int offset) {
    xpos = X_START;
    id = offset;
    // Spaces the horses apart
    ypos = Y_START * offset * 3;
    horse = new Horse(xpos, ypos);
    this.track = track;
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    horse.draw(g2);
}

/**
 * Run method that thread executes and makes horses go across the screen
 * racing.
 */
public void run() {

    while (RUNNING) {

            //varying the x position movement
            horse.setX(xpos += (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1), id);
            // Sleeping the thread
            track.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (xpos >= FINISH_LINE) {
                RUNNING = false;
            }


        }
    }
}




public class Horse {

private int xTop, xStart;
private int yTop, yStart;
public static final int RING_WIDTH = 20, FINISH_LINE=450;
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public Lock lockThing = new ReentrantLock();

public Horse(int x, int y) {
    xTop = x;
    yTop = y;
    xStart = x;
    yStart = y;
}



public void setX(int dx, int id) {
    try{
        lockThing.lock();
        xTop=dx;
        if (dx >= FINISH_LINE){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, id + " Won");
        }

    }finally{ lockThing.unlock();}
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    Ellipse2D.Double horse = new Ellipse2D.Double(xTop, yTop, RING_WIDTH,
            RING_WIDTH);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(horse);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(horse);
}
}



public class TrackPane extends JPanel {

private static final int NUM_OF_HORSES = 5;

private ArrayList<HorseThread> horses = new ArrayList<HorseThread>();
private ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(25);

public TrackPane() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    reset();
}

public void reset() {
    // Should dispose of any running threads...
    horses.clear();
    // Allocating the memory for horses
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_HORSES; i++) {
        horses.add(new HorseThread(this, i + 1));
    }
}

public void start() {
    // Should dispose of any running threads...
    threads.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < horses.size(); i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(horses.get(i));
        thread.start();
        threads.add(thread);
    }
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (HorseThread horse : horses) {
        horse.paint(g);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: *"I believe this is due to them all sharing the same lock and maybe even resources."* This is not how your program works so I'm not sure why you think that. Rather it is the opposite case, your threads have no means to communicate with each other. It seems there is not a way programmed in for the losers to stop early, so why should they?

Comment: I thought the shared variable RUNNING would stop the threads once it was changed to false(inddicating that a circle has won the race)

Comment: RUNNING variable is not shared at all. Each Thread has his own ;)

Comment: `RUNNING` is a private instance variable and you have multiple HorseThreads so it is not shared. Same thing with the ReentrantLock on Horse. And so that is what I was getting at. It seems you have an intent for something to happen here but the code certainly doesn't do it. So really you should explain to us how it's *supposed* to work, otherwise we are left guessing a little.

Comment: The code is supposed to work like this. A menu pops up and gives the option to run the race, reset the race, or quit. When run race is selected, the circles run across the screen until it reaches the finish line. The other circles should stop in their tracks and terminate. I have it working to where the circles race eachother but there is multiple winners. I shall post the other two classes in case anyone wants to run it and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to share RUNNING variable between threads

```
private boolean RUNNING = true;
```

The fastest way to do it (but not the best one) would be changing it to static:

```
private static volatile boolean RUNNING = true;
```

The more proper and blessed way to do it would be creating a component which will be shared between your threads and will take care of synchronization.
Another thing messing around are pop ups:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), id + " Won");
```

Which are blocking a thread until someone closes them and this is preventing your thread from setting RUNNING to false. 
Move this logic to run method of HorseThread and remove it from setX method in Horse class:

```
class HorseThread implements Runnable {

private static volatile boolean RUNNING = true;
public static final int X_START = 10;
public static final int Y_START = 20;
public int FINISH_LINE = 450;
private Horse horse;
private int xpos, ypos;
private TrackPane track;
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public int id;

public HorseThread(TrackPane track, int offset) {
    xpos = X_START;
    id = offset;
    // Spaces the horses apart
    ypos = Y_START * offset * 3;
    horse = new Horse(xpos, ypos);
    this.track = track;
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    horse.draw(g2);
}

/**
 * Run method that thread executes and makes horses go across the screen
 * racing.
 */
public void run() {

    while (RUNNING) {

        //varying the x position movement
        horse.setX(xpos += (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1), id);
        // Sleeping the thread
        track.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (xpos >= FINISH_LINE) {
            RUNNING = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), id + " Won");
        }


    }
    }
}



class Horse {

private int xTop, xStart;
private int yTop, yStart;
public static final int RING_WIDTH = 20, FINISH_LINE=450;
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public Lock lockThing = new ReentrantLock();

public Horse(int x, int y) {
    xTop = x;
    yTop = y;
    xStart = x;
    yStart = y;
}



public void setX(int dx, int id) {
    try{
        lockThing.lock();
        xTop=dx;

    }finally{ lockThing.unlock();}
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    Ellipse2D.Double horse = new Ellipse2D.Double(xTop, yTop, RING_WIDTH,
            RING_WIDTH);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(horse);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(horse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do it using the static volatile example and it still gives me the same results. Posted the other two classes if you would like to see how it runs on the gui.

Comment: Yep, it was much easier to find a problem when I could actually see whats going on ;)